# php - filter_var returns false even with urlencode

Tags: php, character-encoding, urlencode, filter-var

```
$url="http://www.example.com/日本語/こんにちは.html";
$result=filter_var(urlencode($url), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

I am encoding the URL! Then, why is `$return` `false`?

Comment: The URL needs to be `http://example.com/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E/%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF.html`. You cannot easily fix that with a simple function call after the fact only having an invalid URL as a starting point.

Comment: @deceze This is still invalid in the filter.

Comment: @Blackbam …? https://3v4l.org/POAWp

Comment: Excuse me I had a typo ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `urlencode` to encode query parameter values. It encodes characters that have a special meaning in a url, like `:`, `/`, `?`, etc.

If you encode an entire url - as opposed to values in the query section - it is not a valid url any more.

This is your url after you encode it:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%2F%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a valid URL probably:

http://php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.validate.php

From the docs:

> Validates value as URL (according to »
>   http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396), optionally with required
>   components. Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol
>   http:// so further validation may be required to determine the URL
>   uses an expected protocol, e.g. ssh:// or mailto:. Note that the
>   function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid; internationalized
>   domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail.

URL encoded URLs always fail as urlencode adds invalid charactares to the URL. This function is not for validation of URLs with chinese chars.

Especially the last lines say it precisely:  **Note that the
function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid; internationalized
domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail.**

Edit: @jeroen is right btw `urlencode()` is for encoding parameters not whole urls.